# __proto__ : function declaration versus object literal

Tags: javascript, prototype

I've just started reading [this article](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/javascript-the-core/) and I'm stuck on the first paragraph:

> For the code:
>
> var foo = {   x: 10,   y: 20 };
>
> we have the structure with two explicit own properties and one
>   implicit proto property, which is the reference to the prototype
>   of foo:

[image]

> Figure 1. A basic object with a prototype.

My question...

Why does the diagram show a foo prototype for a **basic object literal?**

If I create two objects, it shows this isn't the case:-

- object one - a function object / constructor function
- object two - a basic object literal with key/value pairs like a dictionary

If I use the debugger, it shows that object one does indeed create a One.prototype which also has an Object.prototype further down the chain, but object two does not have a two.prototype, instead it goes straight to the Object.prototype.

[image]

Have i misunderstood the proto concept or is the article incorrect by implying object literals have their own prototype?

---

EDIT:
I've given up reading the article, it's broken English makes a complicated subject more complicated.

The guy in [this video](http://youtu.be/ljNi8nS5TtQ?t=39m48s) answers my question and to sum it up:

- every object has a __ proto __
- **only functions have a prototype**
- prototype is the template used when using new operator

Comment: "All objects in JavaScript are descended from `Object`; all objects inherit methods and properties from `Object.prototype`". https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype

Comment: When you do `{ x: 10, y: 20 }`, you are making a `new Object`.

Comment: @Rocket, yes i understand that, but function constructors create a copy of themselves as a prototype that can be referenced by instances but object literals don't. I just think the article is wrong by using a bad example straight off the bat.

Comment: "When you do { x: 10, y: 20 }, you are making a new Object"...but the article implies this is a foo prototype...it isn't, it's an object prototype

Comment: Depending on how you interpret it.  I think what is meant here is "foo's prototype" which happens to be Object.prototype.  It is a bit confusing/misleading in this case, but is more clear in the next example where clearly "a" is shown to have a `__proto__` of Object.prototype

Comment: Looking at the article further, I believe this was left vague intentionally as this diagram occurs before the explanation of prototype chain and before the author explains what happens when no prototype is set.

Comment: @James Thanks for your comments. I didn't read past the first section so will muddle through the article as per your comments that it clarifies the intent later on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `__proto__` comes from the constructor's `prototype`.

In the first case, `One` is your constructor. You haven't assigned anything to `One.prototype`, so it defaults to a `Object`'s `__proto__` and you get the two levels of inheritance.

If you had added things to that object, they would show up as part of the `One` prototype.

```
function One() {
  this.x = 4;
  this.y = 'hhh';
}
One.prototype.z = 'foobar';

var one = new One();
```

In the second case, you are creating an object literal which has `Object` as it's prototype, so you only inherit from the `Object` prototype. Prototypes are objects themselves, so if you were to add properties to it, like so:

```
foo.__proto__.z = 'foobar';
```

<del>You are modifying the instance of Object that is `foo`'s prototype, it doesn't modify `Object` itself, only that particular instance of it. That is what the article means, by `foo`'s prototype.</del>

I just did a test in V8 and it seems an object literal doesn't have an instance of `Object` as it's prototype, it has `Object`'s `__proto__` itself, so you should not modify `foo.__proto__`, you would be modifying the underlying `Object` prototype that all Objects inherit from. If you do wish do modify it, you should create a new instance of `Object` first to add to:

```
foo.__proto__ = {};
foo.__proto__.z = 'foobar';
```

Example:

```
var x = {};
x.__proto__ = {};
x.__proto__.z = 'foobar';
var y = {};
y.z; // undefined
Object.z; // undefined
```

vs.

```
var x = {};
x.__proto__.z = 'foobar';
var y = {};
y.z; // 'foobar'
Object.z; // 'foobar'
```

In my opinion, it would be better if object literals automatically created a new instance of Object for their `__proto__`. Then again, there is no real reason in modifying the prototype of an object literal.

Also note that you should not use `__proto__` directly, as it is deprecated, and its future replacement is [strongly discouraged as well](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf). You should use [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) for implementing inheritance in Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer; it's a bit too detailed for my beginner brain as i was only trying to clarify why the object literal had a self declared prototype, but your answer alleviated my concerns by stating "...creating an object literal which has Object as it's prototype, so you only inherit from the Object prototype".

Answer (score 1):

There are two interrelated concepts with prototype in JavaScript:

**First**, there is a prototype property that every JavaScript function has (it is empty by default), and you attach properties and methods on this prototype property when you want to implement inheritance.Note that this prototype property is not enumerable: it is not accessible in a for/in loop. But Firefox, and most versions of Safari and Chrome, have a __ proto__ “pseudo” property (an alternative way) that allows you to access an object’s prototype property. You will likely never use this __ proto__ pseudo property, but know that it exists and it is simply a way to access an object’s prototype property in some browsers.
The prototype property is used primarily for inheritance: you add methods and properties on a function’s prototype property to make those methods and properties available to instances of that function.

The **second** concept with prototype in JavaScript is the prototype attribute. Think of the prototype attribute as a characteristic of the object; this characteristic tells us the object’s “parent”. In simple terms: An object’s prototype attribute points to the object’s “parent”—the object it inherited its properties from. The prototype attribute is normally referred to as the prototype object, and it is set automatically when you create a new object.To expound on this: Every object inherits properties from some other object, and it is this other object that is the object’s prototype attribute or “parent.” (You can think of the prototype attribute as the lineage or the parent). In the example code above, newObj‘s prototype is PrintStuff.prototype.

Comment: Source: [Javascript is Sexy](http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-prototype-in-plain-detailed-language/).